# "Multiple object sets per type are not supported", but why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I get the aforementioned error when I try to create two dbsets of the same type:

```
        public DbSet<ForeignExpression> ForeignExpressions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ForeignExpression> Last25Expressions { get; set; }
```

I'm wondering about the reason for that. In this case, a user can add an unlimited number of "ForeignExpressions". I only want to show the last few in the page, so I thought it would be beneficial to store them elsewhere since it's much less costly to query 25 records than thousands. ASP.NET seems to disagree. Why is that so, and what is the recommended way of dealing with this?

(p.s.: I know that I could inherit from ForeignExpression to solve the problem, but I still don't get the philosophy behind this)

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914052/multiple-object-sets-of-the-same-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Linq to EF provider supports deferred execution,  correctly constructing an appropriate LINQ statement will get you what you need, without pulling out thousands of records.  The LINQ to EF provider, given your LINQ statement, will construct a SQL statement with the appropriate filtering.  You might like to use LinqPAD to evidence the SQL emitted by the LINQ to EF provider.