# MVC Multiple object sets per type not supported error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a db context and add a entity controller for autogeneration.

The problem is when i run the controller url i get the following error:

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'Arduinos' and 'Arduinoes' can both contain instances of type 'MVC3.Models.Arduino'

Why is the name "Arduinoes" generated since i specify that the name of the dbset is "Arduinos".

**Model:**

```
public  class DBArduino:DbContext
{
    DbSet<Arduino> Arduinos { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVC3.Models.Arduino> Arduinoes { get; set;}  //this one is autogenerated after adding the "ArduinoController" why does it change its name?
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ArduinoController : Controller
{
    private DBArduino db = new DBArduino();
    // GET: Arduino
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Arduinoes.ToList());
    }
    ....
}
```

Where does he get the "*Arduinoes*" from? Even after I rebuild the solution and add again the controller it still gets this name.

How should the name of the dataset generated by adding the controller with entity be called to work?

Comment: You most likely have 2 classes which are named the same?

Comment: Remove one of the two identical `DbSet`s.

Comment: I followed the MSDN tutorial in which it says first create a dbset in the context class then add the controller based on the context class.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

The "**Arduinoes**" name assigned to auto-generated `DbSet` comes by design in [`System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which considers table class names ending in "o" (except with preceding vocals) added with "*-es*" suffix as shown below:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1308:NormalizeStringsToUppercase")]
private string InternalPluralize(string word)
{
    // other stuff
    if (suffixWord.EndsWith("o", true, this.Culture) || suffixWord.EndsWith("s", true, this.Culture))
    {
        return prefixWord + suffixWord + "es";
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

(complete code view provided inside Github repository on "*Reference*" part below)

Therefore, since required `Arduinoes` property name not found in your `DbContext` class, EF's mechanism related with controller scaffolding added it regardless existence of other `DbSet` property referencing same table class with different property name, hence throwing `InvalidOperationException` due to multiple object set duplication.

If you still want to use controller scaffolding by pre-assigned `DbSet` property, I recommend to remove auto-generated part then change this declaration:

```
public DbSet<Arduino> Arduinos { get; set; }
```

to follow EF's convention:

```
public DbSet<Arduino> Arduinoes { get; set; }
```

or remove manually-declared `DbSet` then using auto-generated one.

**NB:** Duplicate representation referencing same table name in different `DbSet` properties are not supported, hence you may need to follow EF pluralization convention when defining `DbSet` property name with controller scaffolding.

**Reference:**

[System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.EnglishPluralizationService Reference Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.Entity.Design/System/Data/Entity/Design/PluralizationService/EnglishPluralizationService.cs)

Similar issues:

[Multiple object sets of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914052/multiple-object-sets-of-the-same-type)

[ASP.NET Identity - Multiple object sets per type are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343246/asp-net-identity-multiple-object-sets-per-type-are-not-supported?noredirect=1&lq=1)